# Return a single variable value (string) from the model and fill it in the text field of view - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following Model, Controller and view. Using PHP Point of Sale 11.3. 
I'm trying to take the max value in a DB column and display it in a text field in view.

Model:

```
function getmax()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT max(item_id) FROM phppos_items");
    return $query->row();
}
```

Controller:

```
function view()
{   
    $data['max_id']=$this->Item->getmax();      
    $this->load->view("items/form",$data);
}
```

View:

```
<?php 

    echo $max_id; //line 16. Error Here.

    echo form_input(array(
                        'name'=>'item_number',
                        'id'=>'item_number',
                        'value'=>set_value('item_number',$max_id)) //is this right??
                    );
?>
```

Am getting two errors when execution.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: 4096
Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
Filename: items/form.php
Line Number: 16

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
Filename: helpers/form_helper.php
Line Number: 625
```

I'm getting the max_id without any issues when used as dropdown in view.

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('max_id',$max_id);?>
```

But I need this value to be filled in default in the form text field. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should have been like this

Model

```
function getmax()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT max(item_id) as MaxID FROM phppos_items");
    return $query->row();
}
```

Controller

```
function view()
{   
    $data['row']=$this->Item->getmax();      
    $this->load->view("items/form",$data);
}
```

View

```
$options['name']    =   'item_number';
$options['id']      =   'item_number';
$options['value']   =   set_value('item_number',$row->MaxID);

echo form_input($options);
```

You see i am using row

Answer (score 1):

use in your view:

```
$max_id->max
```

and in your sql in the model change it to:

```
"SELECT max(item_id) AS max FROM phppos_items"
```

See if that works